# Are there any place where I can get legitimate software via torrent?

Tags: download, bittorrent, file-download

The internet speed I have far exceeds the speeds I'm able to access via some sites to download software.

Example:
[image: slow download example]

I've discovered that torrent is a good solution for this, Ubuntu ISO files being a good example where vendor provides both direct and torrent options, and torrent is always faster for me.

Is there some legal issues that prevent such sites from existing? User can validate SHASUM of the downloaded file against the expected results so tampering is IMO not one of the valid reasons.

Perhaps a search engine that I can search for torrents containing files with a specific SHA256. –

Comment: Legitimate paid software does not exist as a torrent or simply cannot be trusted

Comment: Cracked/modified ones sure. But if sha256sum matches, it's the same file, then it's just a mean to obtain the binaries/archive/package then I can still proceed to put in license keys etc.

Comment: It's possible an org that does licensing like MS does might make this work, but it's very unlikely. Regardless, this is a hypothetical question and not suited for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I understand the question as if the author is looking for software installation media that a legitimite buyer will get from the vendor anyway. The reasoning that his torrent speed is higher than the speed of other downloads is just a pretexte trying to get illegal download locations.

Comment: You can sometimes use an HTTP download manager that uses multiple connections for the same file to the same effect.

Comment: @DanielB yup. Although for this case, my download speed was resolved by removing a specific http header in the requests that says "I am using a free personal license". Using URL for a "free trial" was 1000x faster.

Comment: > is just a pretexte trying to get illegal download locations. 

Not the case. Illegal stuff is way too easy to find. I am talking legitimate vendor provided files that community collectively hosts to increase download speed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply - its not needed. In *most* cases the bandwidth costs and hosting costs are a relatively small part of the costs of doing business, and where a peer to peer software delivery system is needed, they build their own (for example windows uses a peer to peer software update system for updates).

You'd need a mix of software that's *popular* with lots of seeders with development and maintenance revenue low enough that throwing up a file on a server isn't worth it.

You'd also not need to worry about it being licenced or not, so it would entirely be *large* pieces of open source, no cost or similar software.

The intersection here is just *really* small.

Comment: Blizzard for years use a torrent like system to release patches to World of Warcraft. It wasn’t very effective or liked by the community

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any place where I can get legitimate software via torrent?

Yes, e.g. https://archive.org/details/software. Each archive can be downloaded via torrent.

Comment: Perhaps a search engine that I can search for torrents containing files with a specific SHA256.